# Dynamic invoke of a method using named parameters

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, named-parameters, roslyn

We're currently using .NET 3.5 and part of our application uses dynamic invocation (using [MethodBase.Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodbase.invoke.aspx))

I am wondering if it is possible to mix in Named Parameters (in .NET 4) with dynamic invocation, to perform something similar to:

```
// Dictionary that holds parameter name --> object mapping
var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();

// Add parameters ....

// Invoke where each parameter will match the one from the method signature.
methodInfo.Invoke(obj, parameters);
```

Is there any API that allows this option out of the box? If not, is it possible to develop some solution to perform this?

EDIT:

Rethinking of this problem, it sounds similar to how the compiler may actually need to match method calls based on argument lists. Perhaps there's some Compiler API (or the new Roslyn project) that allows doing just this easily? (without coding it myself which may be prone to errors).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use code like this:

```
public static class ReflectionExtensions {

    public static object InvokeWithNamedParameters(this MethodBase self, object obj, IDictionary<string, object> namedParameters) { 
        return self.Invoke(obj, MapParameters(self, namedParameters));
    }

    public static object[] MapParameters(MethodBase method, IDictionary<string, object> namedParameters)
    {
        string[] paramNames = method.GetParameters().Select(p => p.Name).ToArray();
        object[] parameters = new object[paramNames.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < parameters.Length; ++i) 
        {
            parameters[i] = Type.Missing;
        }
        foreach (var item in namedParameters)
        {
            var paramName = item.Key;
            var paramIndex = Array.IndexOf(paramNames, paramName);
            if (paramIndex >= 0)
            {
                parameters[paramIndex] = item.Value;
            }
        }
        return parameters;
    }
}
```

And then call it like this:

```
var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
// Add parameters ...
methodInfo.InvokeWithNamedParameters(obj, parameters);
```

Comment: What would happen if the method uses default parameter values (.NET 4 feature)? does this solution work in that case? (can it differentiate between a null passed parameter, to a parameter that should not be passed (and thus take the default value)? I am not sure, but i will take the code and test that!

Comment: @lysergic-acid: look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421994/invoking-methods-with-optional-parameters-through-reflection/2422015#2422015) for some ideas.

Comment: awesome so basically i can amend your example to reflect for these attributes and get the default value into the array in any case. Thanks!

Comment: I've changed the code to initialize the parameters with `Type.Missing` to account for optional parameters. But I haven't tested it, please check that it works.

Comment: You might want to check if `paramIndex != -1` before you set the value to prevent `IndexOutOfRangeException`.

Comment: @Fred: You're absolutely right, a more robust implementation would need to not only do that but also check if `namedParameters` is null and many other boundary conditions.

Comment: What other boundary conditions?  Given inputs of a MethodBase (literally any instance) and a dictionary populated with virtually any parameter names and objects, the ONLY thing you'd really need to check here for this to not blow up is that `paramIndex > -1`. If you simply added that one thing that the last comment asked for, this would simply work. It would ignore parameters in the dictionary that don't match any in the method, and would just work as expected. Valid arguments would always make it to the correct place, and beyond that, it's outside the responsibility of this method.

Comment: Hey @Triynko, makes sense! Edited the answer.

Answer (score 1):

you can get your paramter names with the help of this article [How can you get the names of method parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/214086/how-can-you-get-the-names-of-method-parameters-in-c) and then you can reorder them to invoke them as described here [Reflection: How to Invoke Method with parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2202381/reflection-how-to-invoke-method-with-parameters)

Answer (score 1):

With .net4, I have an opensource framework ImpromptuInterface (found in nuget) that makes it easy to use the DLR apis for [late invocation including named/optional parameters](http://code.google.com/p/impromptu-interface/wiki/UsageReallyLateBinding#Named/Optional_Arguments).

```
var result = Impromptu.InvokeMember(target, "MyMethod", parameters.Select(pair=>  InvokeArg.Create(pair.Key, pair.Value)).Cast<object>().ToArray());
```