# Can a method determine at run-time if a parameter has been defaulted?

Tags: c#, methods, optional-parameters

Given this example code, is there a way for the method **foo** to determine at run-time that the 4th parameter hes been defaulted?

```
using System;

namespace DefaultParameters {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            int a = 0,b = 1,c = 3;
            foo(a, b, c);       // The 4th parm is defaulted in the method definition.
            foo(a, b, c, 100);  // The 4th parm is explicit in the method call.
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// A method with a default paramater
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="speed">Speed</param>
        /// <param name="brightness">Brightness</param>
        /// <param name="weight">Weight</param>
        /// <param name="humidity">Humidity</param>
        public static void foo(int speed, int brightness, int weight, int humidity = 42) {
            Console.WriteLine("speed = " + speed + " brightness = " + brightness + " weight = " + weight + " humidity  = " + humidity);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the better [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20886811/check-inside-method-whether-some-optional-argument-was-passed) is to overloads the method like in the first answer.

Answer (score 0):

## No

You could take some liberty and guess that if it *is* the default value, it probably wasn't given, but there is no way to know for sure.