# How to call the method with optional arguments dynamically?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, methods, default-value

I need your help.

Is it possible to do the following using c#?

I have a method

```
void SomeMethod(int p1 = 0, bool p2 = true, string p3 = "")
{
    // some code
}
```

And I need to call this method with unknown number of arguments on compile time. I mean on runtime the app should load info about arguments from xml (for example) and call the method with those arguments. Xml file may contains 0 to 3 arguments.

How to call the *SomeMethod* method with unknown number of arguments loaded from xml?

Thank you

Comment: Is 3 the max amount of args or is there possibly more as you can use the same name in function names with different args.

Comment: Karl, no, 3 args are for example. It could be 10 or even 20.

Comment: Why not just have List<Int>, List<String>, List<Boolean>  ... ?

Comment: Because of each argument has unique role in method. This is not just list of ids or list of names of something.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it using reflection:

- Obtain [`MethodInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodbase.getparameters%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) passing all three parameter types.
- Obtain run-time parameter values
- Obtain parameter metadata [`ParameterInfo\[\]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.parameterinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) from `MethodInfo` by calling `GetParameters()`
- For each missing parameter, check `HasDefaultValue`, and grab [`DefaultValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.parameterinfo.defaultvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) if it does
- Append an array of default values to the array of values passed in. You will have an array of three objects
- Pass the resultant array to the method that you obtained using reflection.

Comment: Good solution. I'll try to do it like this. Thanks.

Comment: +1... Readable and good to learn reflection, but correct one is to pass `Type.Missing` as arguments - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421994/invoking-methods-with-optional-parameters-through-reflection

Answer (score 0):

Read in the arguments into the variables and depending on how many were found, call SomeMethod. For example if you have valid values for p1, call SomeMethod(p1); valid values for p1 and p2, SomeMethod(p1, p2)...so on and so forth.

Comment: This is not gonna work. Because in case of 10 arguments I'll need to "hardcode" a lot of combinations.

Comment: oh ok. That is what I was wondering if you had variable number of arguments. I think then what @dasblinkenlight proposes will.